# What is the product of the following reaction(different sources give different answers)

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, experimental-chemistry, bond, salt

$$\ce{FeS +dil HNO3}$$
$$\ce{FeS +conc HNO3}$$

I got different answers to these reactions in different sources

Source1 Jd lee:[image]

Source 2 Op Tandon:
[image]

Can anyone please explain which is the correct one and the reason for the same

Comment: Please don't use images in place of text, add conditions, cite the sources.

Comment: What do you mean you "*don't have idea about the sources*"? Was it someone else who wrote this question for you? Source 1 looks like a handout from a lecture/presentation, and source 2 looks like a scan from a textbook. Add corresponding references for both, it's that simple. All third-party sources must be cited, the preferred citation style for references is ACS.

Comment: As for markup, please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown. Please spare colloquialisms and slang for informal chatting, this isn't the right place for either.

Answer (score 3):

Whatever the experimental conditions, $\ce{FeS}$ does react with any acid $\ce{HX}$ like $\ce{HNO3}$ according to $$\ce{FeS + 2 HX -> FeX2 + H2S}$$ This reaction proceeds like this if the acidic solution is rather diluted. If  $\ce{HNO3}$ is more concentrated, both $\ce{H2S}$ and $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ may be oxidized according to one of the following equations : $$\ce{H2S + 2 HNO3 -> S + 2 H2O + 2 NO2}$$  $$\ce{H2S + 8 HNO3 -> H2SO4 + 8 NO2 + 4 H2O}$$ $$\ce{Fe^{2+} + HNO3 + H+ ->  Fe^{3+} + NO2 + H2O}$$
It is hard to know which ones of these equations is favored at a given concentration of nitric acid.